# How to enable overflowing elements display over another block element

Tags: css, html

Please take a look at the snapshot of the page

[image: Overflow error in circle]

I have no idea what's wrong. Why can't the drop down from the navigation simply display on top of the elements in the side bar.

Thanks for the help. And oh, I'm a beginner in CSS.

Comment: You need to include your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set that element to::

```
#nav{
  z-index:9999;
}
```

since you are learning about it, [check this out:::](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/), this will help you to understand the z-index position of a div(element) in a page.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the annoying problem. The link also helped a lot.

Comment: no problem, think about like layers and you will never have the problem again :-)